# Can I put a lua_table in another table to build a multi-dimensional array via C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, lua, lua-table

for my game im trying to accomplish the following array structure by C++ because the data come from an external source and should be available in a lua_script.

The array structure should look like this: (The data are in a map, the map contains the name of the variable and a list of Pairs (Each pair is a key value pair considered to be one element in one subarray)...

The data prepared in the map are complete and the structure is definetly okay.
So basically I have

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::list<std::pair> >;
                  /\index(e.g: sword) /\       /\
                                      ||       ||
                                      ||    Pair: Contains two strings (key/value pair)
                                      ||
                                      List of Pairs for each array
```

---

```
items = {
    ["sword"] = {item_id = 1294, price = 500},
    ["axe"] = {item_id = 1678, price = 200},
    ["red gem"] = {item_id = 1679, price = 2000},
}
```

What I got so far now is:

```
for(ArrayMap::iterator it = this->npc->arrayMap.begin(); it != this->npc->arrayMap.end(); it++) {
    std::string arrayName = (*it).first;
    if((*it).second.size() > 0) {
        lua_newtable(luaState);
        for(ArrayEntryList::iterator itt = (*it).second.begin(); itt != (*it).second.end(); itt++) {
            LuaScript::setField(luaState, (*itt).first.c_str(), (*itt).second.c_str());
        }
        lua_setglobal(luaState, arrayName.c_str());
    }
}
```

But this will only generate the following structure:

```
(table)
[item_id] = (string) 2000
[name] = (string) sword
[price] = (string) 500
```

The problem is that the table can ofcourse only contain each index once.
Thatswhy I need something like "a table in a table", is that possible?

Is there a way to achieve this? Im glad for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, if you have two "sword", then you can not store second one? If that's the case, you are doing it wrong. The key of map should be unique and if you decide that you are going to use `std::map` to store your items then your external source should provide unique keys. I used `std::string` as key in my previous game. Example:

```
"WeakSword" -> { some more data }
"VeryWeakSword" -> { some more data }
```

or, with your data (assuming item_ids are unique) you can get something like following from external source:

```
1294 -> { some more data }
1678 -> { some more data }
```

I'm not sure how efficient is this but I wasn't programming a hardware-hungry 3D bleeding-edge game so it just did a fine job.

The data structure that you are using also depends on the how you are going to use it. For example, if you are always iterating through this structure why don't you store as follows:

```
class Item {public: ... private: std::string name; int id; int value;}
std::vector<Item> items // be careful tho, std::vector copies item before it pushes
```

Extract(or Parse?) the actual value you want from each entity in external source and store them in `std::vector`. Reaching the middle of `std::vector` is expensive, however, if your intention is not instant accessing but rather iterating over data, why use map? But, if your intention is actually reaching a specific key/value pair, you should alter your external data and use unique keys.

Finally, there is also another associative container that stores non-unique key/value pairs called `std::multimap` but I really doubt you *really* need it here.

Comment: Hmm I think you got me wrong or I explained it wrong. The item-name's and ids are unique but I need to assign each table field an array instead of a single value because each item can have a optional amount of of data.

Comment: std::map<std::string, std::vector<Property>> where Properties is the structure that you can create in order to store some data and key is the name (or you can make it id, in that case key would be int). According to your example, you can create a Property structure/class that carries variable number of fields like int id, std::vector<int> prices/costs etc.